# Get the module a variable is defined in

Tags: python, module

When I define a class

```py
class X:
    pass
```

I can then easily see the module name where the class is defined by doing `X.__module__`.

When I want to do the same for a variable

```py
a = 5
a.__module__
```

I get an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__module__'`.

Is there any way how I can get the module name where a variable is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because variables in Python are not separate objects. If you write `a=5;a.__module__`, that is treated exactly identically to `(5).__module__`, and that doesn't make any sense since you probably have multiple variables pointing to the integer `5`.

This isn't really possible for classes either, for the same reason: `X.__module__` actually returns the module in which the class was created, even if you create another variable referring to the class in a different module.

There are certain exotic situations in which this can in theory work, such as defining a class with a metaclass with a custom `__prepare__` method, or if the code is being `exec`ed with a custom `locals` object, but those are very unusual and outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: I was afraid of this not being possible. Can you think of another workaround than by making the `a` variable a field of a class, whose metaclass tells `a` in which module it is?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? The last paragraph of my answer was mainly trying to defend it against pedants, not an actual attempt at a solution.

Comment: Ugh, that is almost worth another question :). I am writing a small GraphQL API generator and I would like to support actions not related to any particular type. The easiest for the user would be to have a dictionary with all those actions and then just pass it into the generator. However, I would like things like this to work: `"action": Action(return_value=ObjectType("Person"))`, which would refer to class Person defined in the same module as the dictionary with the action. And while writing this, I realized that I actually never run into import issues and can just pass the class reference.

Comment: I am sorry for using you as a rubber duck :)